# Silex, add route when necessary

Tags: php, server, silex

I'm making a web JSON application, and I would like to make a version router. Like, I could have the path `/v0.0/../..` and `/v0.1/../..`

And I wonder if it is possible not to load every route but just load the route with the good version.

Answer (score 0):

You could check what URL has been requested using `$_SERVER` global variable before creating routes using `$app->get(...`.

However, this isn't an ideal solution and I think it's not even necessary. The overhead caused by creating routes that aren't used is very small, basically none. Silex uses Dependency Injection (http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) which makes it very efficient and controllers that aren't used aren't even instantiated.

So I think you don't need to worry about defining more routes that necessary.

Comment: In some cases you can't define all routes. In a project I've created the end user can create extra content which each have their own route. Each of those routes need to be calculated, so for this project it was easier to indeed to parse the request uri, test if the route leads to valid one and then register the route into silix